# Convert video codecs to vp9 to mp4?

Tags: javascript, video, getusermedia, amazon-rekognition, web-mediarecorder

I am recording the video from the getUserMedia function in js with option

```
let options = {mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp9'};
// here mediaStreamObj is stream returning from the getUserMedia
let mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStreamObj, options);
```

I want the codecs to be h264 I have also tried
video/webm;codecs=h264
in this it is giving mime type as video/x-matroska
[image]

video/mp4;codecs=h264 - not supported throws error

I need mimeType as mp4 and codecs h264.

As I am working on a video analysis (amazon recognition). and I want to use startLabelDetection in php for detecting the labels in the video and amazon only accept h264 format video.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-rekognition-2016-06-27.html#startlabeldetection

Is there anyone I can convert the video mime-type to mp4 with js(preferrable) or php, so that I can use it with amazon rekognition for video analysis?

Expected mimetype:

[image]

You can check the mime type here https://www.metadata2go.com/

Comment: you may be interested to know that *The WebM container is based on a profile of Matroska*

Comment: looking at mdn docs ... `video/mp4; codecs="avc1.4d002a"`? there's good explanation for what to put after the `.` in [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/codecs_parameter#AVC_profiles)

Comment: @JaromandaX it is not supported in chrome (js) , you can check it by ```MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.4d002a')``` it will give value false. My main aim that I get the video with h264 codecs so that I can use it on aws recognition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr** You can't get MP4 from your browsers' [MediaRecorder APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder). You can, I believe, get Amazon's Elastic Transcoder to convert webm to mp4. You should also try to feed your webm / h.264 files to Rekognition if you have not already done so.

As you've realized, there are two parts to your requirement, boxing and video. We need a bit of vocabulary to answer your question in detail.

### Boxing

First up is the so-called "boxing" or container format. [*webm*](https://www.webmproject.org/about/) is a format based on [Matroska](https://www.matroska.org/index.html), based in turn on [Extensible Binary Markup Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Binary_Meta_Language) (EBML). EBML was developed for Matroska. It's like XML but takes less RAM and disk space because it's not nearly as verbose.  [*webm*](https://www.webmproject.org/about/) itself is an open and royalty-free standard for media files.

Another boxing format is [MPEG-4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_14)'s. It's almost identical to Apple's *mov* movie-file format and is called the *mp4* format.

WebRTC has its own boxing schemes adapted to datagram (instead of data stream) communications. Out of the scope of your question.

### Codec

What goes in those webm or mp4 boxes? Audio and video data.   (They can also contain other time-synchronized data streams like captions, as needed.)

- [*h.264*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Video_Coding) also known as Advanced Video Coding, MPEG-4 Part 10, or AVC.
- [*vp8*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VP8), the open-source and patent free codec developed by On2 acquired by Google
- [*h.265*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Video_Coding) also known as High Efficiency Video Coding or HEVC.
- [*vp9*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VP9), the more recent open source and patent free codec developed at Google.

The latter two, newer, codecs require more compute cycles to compress. And h.265 is still subject to a significant patent burden. So browsers and other general-purpose software typically use the first two, h.265 and vp8.

### What can browsers handle?

Chromium browsers (Google Chrome, Edge) and Firefox have the [MediaRecorder API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder). They can generate webm-boxed data streams containing audio and/or video. They *cannot generate mp4-boxed data streams.*

Those data streams from those browsers can (as of October 2020) contain VP8 or H.264-coded video.  In the case of video data, the [available MIME types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/codecs_parameter) are

- `video/webm; codecs="vp8"` (for vp8)
- `x-matroska/webm; codecs="avc1.42E01E"` or `video/webm; codecs="avc1.42E01E"` for H.264.

Formally speaking you should use `x-matroska/video` rather than `webm/video` as the MIME type for video streams using H.264, even though either MIME type works in browsers. The webm standard requires its video codecs to be either vp8 or vp9, so `video/webm; codecs="avc1.42E01E"`, formally speaking, does not conform to that standard.

### Javascript modules

- [npm ebml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ebml) can unbox and box data into webm streams. I've used its unboxing capability in large scale production. It works.
- [npm mp4-box-encoding](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mp4-box-encoding) can box data into mp4 streams. I haven't used this.

Comment: I've spent way too much time trying to figure out all these MIME type situations by  trial and error. The MediaRecorder API really needs an `enumerateSupportedTypes()` call. I hope this writeup saves somebody else the time I spent.

Comment: How did you configure or call enumerateSupportedTypes() for MediaRecorder API?